# Convert str to unicode str

Tags: python, python-2.x

I need to convert a str to text in Python 2.7

```
a = u'"\u0274\u1d1c\u0274\u1d04\u1d00 \u1d00\u028f\u1d1c\u1d05\u1d07s \u1d00 \u1d1c\u0274 \u0274\u026a\xf1\u1d0f \u1d0f \u1d1c\u0274\u1d00 \u0274\u026a\xf1\u1d00 \u1d04\u1d0f\u0274 \u1d1c\u0274\u1d00 \u1d1b\u1d00\u0280\u1d07\u1d00 \u1d07\u0274 \u029f\u1d00 \u01eb\u1d1c\u1d07 s\u026a\u1d07\u0274\u1d1b\u1d07 \u01eb\u1d1c\u1d07 \u1d18\u1d1c\u1d07\u1d05\u1d07 \u1d1b\u1d07\u0274\u1d07\u0280 \u1d07x\u026a\u1d1b\u1d0f"'
```

I try with `a.decode('utf8')` but the truth is I don't know what kind of code is the str `a`

The output I need is:

```
"ɴᴜɴᴄᴀ ᴀʏᴜᴅᴇs ᴀ ᴜɴ ɴɪñᴏ ᴏ ᴜɴᴀ ɴɪñᴀ ᴄᴏɴ ᴜɴᴀ ᴛᴀʀᴇᴀ ᴇɴ ʟᴀ ǫᴜᴇ sɪᴇɴᴛᴇ ǫᴜᴇ ᴘᴜᴇᴅᴇ ᴛᴇɴᴇʀ ᴇxɪᴛᴏ"
```

ERROR:

```
>>> print(a)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "F:\WinPython-64bit-2.7.13.1Zero\python-2.7.13.amd64\lib\encodings\cp437.py", line 12, in encode
    return codecs.charmap_encode(input,errors,encoding_map)
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode characters in position 1-5: character maps to <undefined>
```

Comment: Just print this string and you'll see its contents. It's like you see `\n` instead of "real" newlines - it's string representation, not what you display.

Comment: A simple `print(a)` would work.

Comment: `a` is a valid JSON string. Is it *intended* to be valid JSON? If so, `json.loads(a)`.

Comment: I just add the error

Comment: Also: "Convert str to unicode str." - it's already a unicode string, see `u` at the beginning of the string definition, before string's contents

Answer (score 1):

Since you are on Python2, you have to *encode*  the string contents - which are already text, to your terminal encoding.

So, if you are on windows, `print(a.encode("cp-850"))`, if you are on Linux,  Mac-OS, or other O.S.: `print(a.encode("utf-8"))`

On Python3 the encoding should be done automatically.
Also,  it is important to understand that characters codified like `\uNNNN` in Python correspond to Unicode codepoints - and not to specific character encodings like "utf-8", "latin1" or "utf-16".  In Python 3 most readable characters encoding like this will be shown even with the string internal representation, which is displayed by default in a Python interactive session (otherwise use the built-in `repr` call to see it). By using the built-in "str" or a call to `print`, you see the rendered string, and all `\uXXXX`, `\UXXXXXXXX`, `\xNN` and `\N{unicode character name}` tokens are rendered as the actual characters. (In Python2 you need to manually encode this representation to the character encoding used in your device)

In other words, if you are using Python 3, this is as simple as:

```
In [15]: a = u'"\u0274\u1d1c\u0274\u1d04\u1d00 \u1d00\u028f\u1d1c\u1d05\u1d07s \u1d00 \u1d1c\u0274 \u0274\u026a\xf1\u1d0f \u1d0f \u1d1c\u0274\u1d00 \u0274\u026a\xf1\u1d00 \u1d04\u1d0f\u0274 \u1d1c\u0274\u1d00 \u1d1b\u1d00\u0280\u1d07\u1d00 \u1d07\u0274 \u029f\u1d00 \u01eb\u1d1c\u1d07 s\u026a\u1d07\u0274\u1d1b\u1d07 \u01eb\u1d1c\u1d07 \u1d18\u1d1c\u1d07\u1d05\u1d07 \u1d1b\u1d07\u0274\u1d07\u0280 \u1d07x\u026a\u1d1b\u1d0f"' 
    ...:                                                                                                                                                            

In [16]: a                                                                                                                                                          
Out[16]: '"ɴᴜɴᴄᴀ ᴀʏᴜᴅᴇs ᴀ ᴜɴ ɴɪñᴏ ᴏ ᴜɴᴀ ɴɪñᴀ ᴄᴏɴ ᴜɴᴀ ᴛᴀʀᴇᴀ ᴇɴ ʟᴀ ǫᴜᴇ sɪᴇɴᴛᴇ ǫᴜᴇ ᴘᴜᴇᴅᴇ ᴛᴇɴᴇʀ ᴇxɪᴛᴏ"'

Or:
In [17]: print(a)                                                                                                                                                   
"ɴᴜɴᴄᴀ ᴀʏᴜᴅᴇs ᴀ ᴜɴ ɴɪñᴏ ᴏ ᴜɴᴀ ɴɪñᴀ ᴄᴏɴ ᴜɴᴀ ᴛᴀʀᴇᴀ ᴇɴ ʟᴀ ǫᴜᴇ sɪᴇɴᴛᴇ ǫᴜᴇ ᴘᴜᴇᴅᴇ ᴛᴇɴᴇʀ ᴇxɪᴛᴏ"
```